# Good dual monitor 10.04 video card?

Tags: graphics, 10.04, video, hardware

Working with a single monitor is getting old and it was a bit of a [pain](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11223913&postcount=16) getting the Intel Sandy Bridge Integrated Graphics working with 10.04. What is a good 10.04 plug and play dual monitor video card with 2 HDMI ports? It will be used with 2 ViewSonic [VX2450wm-LED](http://www.viewsonic.com/products/vx2450wmled.htm) monitors at 1920 x 1080. It won't be used for high performance apps like gaming but may be used to stream video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two different desktops with which I use dual monitors*.  One has a nVidia card, the other has AMD Radeon.  Both work very well, although the nVidia was **far** easier to get working.  (Note, my nVidia desktop is running 10.04, the other is running 11.10)

Unless you're doing pretty intense video editing or gaming, the specific model of card isn't all that important.  Things to look for:

1. Has the output connections you want to use.
2. Has enough memory to support your desired total resolution.

*I only have room for 3 monitors on my desk, so I don't actually do both at the same time...

Just looked it up: my computer has a "nForce 750a SLI" graphic chip with 512 MB of RAM.  This is actually integrated into my motherboard, so I can't recommend a specific card model.

Answer (score 1):

I have a nVidia GeForce 210 that is both extremely inexpensive and works well with the restricted nVidia drivers.  I'm pretty sure mine is branded EVGA.  It can be had for $20-30.